# Passing Value to Function to lookup web site

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a function to pass a values in Column A to the function, but can't seem to get the format correct.

```
   Function GetClassNames(cell As Range) As Variant

   Dim MyCell As String
   MyCell = cell.value

objIE.navigate "www.mysite.com/archive.aspx?code=" & Range(MyCell).Text
```

Here is the working Subroutine

```
Sub GetNames()

Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim objIE As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim result As String

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "https://www.cattle.com/markets/archive.aspx?code=" & Range("A1").Text

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 2

Set HTML = objIE.document

Set elements = HTML.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item")

For Each element In elements
    If element.className = "list-group-item" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, y).Value = element.innerText
        Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    y = y + 1
    End If

Next element

End Sub
```

Comment: How does `r` and the `cell` parameter correlate? I see no discernable link between the two but they seem to both serve the same purpose. Shouldn't it be closer to `MyCell = cell.Value`?

Comment: That was left over from an example online.  I changed it to MyCell=cell.value and now ie opens, but the url is not working.

Comment: not enough information to provide additional assistance.

Comment: the & Range(MyCell).Text section does not seems to be passing the correct value.

Comment: Your original code works like a VBA version of INDIRECT. If you have ="A2" in A1 and call GetClassNames(A1) then it retrieves the value from A2 into MyCell.

Comment: ... but I'm not here to play Twenty Questions so please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the question with the original subroutine that works, I want convert it to a function.

Comment: Are you aware that you cannot change the value of any cell other than the cell that contains a UDF from a UDF on the worksheet? The function may work when called from a sub procedure but will not work when called from teh worksheet.

Comment: Nope did not know that.  Thanks will have to look at another way of doing this.